# Jsonconvert serializeobject not escaping single quote

Tags: c#, json, serialization

C#, I have an Automobile class and in that class i have a vehicleTrim field.
I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to serialize that class and it is not escaping the single quote.
This is causing an issue when i try to set the value of an object in the web via `window.localStorage.setItem` function.

example:

```
public class Automobile
{
    public string vehicleTrim { get; set; }
}

var test = new Automobile()
{
    vehicleTrim = "designer's package"
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.None);
// serialized output: {"vehicleTrim":"designer's package"}
// expected output :  {"vehicleTrim":"designer\'s package"}
```

so now i want to set this json object to the localstorage of my web by calling this

```
var jsSetScript = $"window.localStorage.setItem('automobile', '{serialized}');";
await Control.EvaluateJavascriptAsync(jsSetScript);
```

EvaluateJavascriptAsync returns this error trying to read the json `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 's'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.`

I manaully tried this with the escaped single quote and it was fine. So the question is how can i make serializedobject method escape the single quote?

Comment: The single quote character in a string is valid JSON, so `JsonConvert` has no need or reason to escape it. If you are going to be embedding it into an `eval` string the way you are doing, you're going to have to manually escape it yourself after serialization. (i.e. `serialized.Replace("'", "\\'");`)

Comment: hmm i c so the way i embed it inside the eval is sketchy. Guess ill have to manaully escape it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"\'"` is not even a valid JSON string literal.  From the [JSON spec](https://json.org/):

[image: JSON string specification]

Thus `'` does not need to be escaped, but if it is, it must appear as `"\u0027"`.  Only the 8 listed characters have a special, abbreviated escaping syntax.  (For further details see [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7).)

If `"\u0027"` meets your needs, then setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_StringEscapeHandling.htm) to `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml` should do the trick.  From the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm):

> **StringEscapeHandling Enumeration**
>
> Specifies how strings are escaped when writing JSON text.
>
> ```
> Default           0   Only control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
> EscapeNonAscii    1   All non-ASCII and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
> EscapeHtml        2   HTML (<, >, &, ', ") and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
> ```

Thus the following now succeeds:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml,
};
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.None, settings);

Console.WriteLine(serialized);
// Outputs {"vehicleTrim":"designer\u0027s package"}

Assert.IsTrue(!serialized.Contains('\'')); 
// Succeeds
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p6hDID).